# backbone.js model is not a costructor into router

Tags: backbone.js, initialization, javascript-namespaces

I have a problem with a backbone.js namespacing app demo, i'm trying to display a simple list of element stored locally, when i call the app the console retrieves this error

```
App.model.club is not a constructor
```

the portionof code is in the router secion;

```
 initialize: function () {
   console.log('App.router Initialized');
   App.clubCollection = new App.collection.clubs();
   localStorage.clear();
   App.clubCollection.create(new App.model.club({id: 1, name:'Open Baladin', category: 'Pubs'}));
   App.clubCollection.create(new App.model.club({id: 2, name:'Ai marmi', category: 'Ristorante'}));
   App.clubCollection.create(new App.model.club({id: 3, name:'Branca Leone', category: 'Disco'}));

},
```

the error accoured at the fifth line in the above partion code.

this is the namespace file app.js:

```
window.App = {
model:  {},
view:   {},
collection: {},
router:  {},
util: {},
data: {},
contentHolder : $('#app').find(":jqmData(role='content')"),
container:$('#app'),

init: function() {
    console.log('window.App Initialized')
    new App.router();
    Backbone.history.start();
}
}
```

an this is the module file:

```
App.model.club = App.model.club || {}

App.model.club = Backbone.Model.extend({

defaults: {
    'id' : 1
    'name' : 'Open Baladin',
    'category' : 'Pubs'
},

initialize: function() {
    console.log('App.model.club initialized');
}
});
```

Comment: be sure you declare the `App.model.club` before you use it. Try to debug a little bit with `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot à comma after 'id': 1

Comment: yes, now i got the same error on my view...i'll check the sintax, thankyou!